# How do i push uploaded image file in my template input for update in django 2.0

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-2.0

I want to open a particular record in html template in update mode for which i want every value which was inserted before for this record be in those field, i got every required value in field for text field but in file field which contains image ,it shows no file selected where as i want the image file name(url) in there.

I havent used django form rather i used normal bootstrap forms.

models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

class Product(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    pub_date = models.DateTimeField()
    body = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')   # i m facing problem for this field
    icon = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/')   # i m facing problem for this field as well 
    url = models.TextField()
    votes_total = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    hunter = models.ForeignKey(User,on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
    def summary(self):
        return self.body[:100]
    def short_pub_date(self):
        return self.pub_date.strftime('%b %e %Y')
```

#

views.py

```
def myproducts_update(request,product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
    print(product.image)          # this prints the name of the file (images/37003.jpeg)
    return render(request,'products/myproducts_update.html',{'product':product})
```

templates(myproducts_update.html)

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}

{% block content %}
{% if error %}
{{error}}

{% endif %}
<br>
<br>
<div class="container">
  <div class="jumbotron">

    <h2>Update Product</h2>
  <form action="{% url 'create' %}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="title">Title:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="email" value={{product.title}} placeholder="please enter title" name="title" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="body">Description:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="body" value={{product.body}} placeholder="Description" name="body" required>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="url">URL:</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" id="url" value={{product.url}} placeholder="please enter url" name="url" required>
    </div>
    <br>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="icon">
            <strong>Icon:</strong></label>
          <input type="file"  id="icon"  name="icon" value={{product.icon}} required>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-6">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for="url">
            <strong>Image:</strong></label>
          <input type="file"  id="image" placeholder="please enter url" name="image" value={{product.image}} required>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

<br>


    <input type="submit" value="Update Product" class="btn btn-primary">

  </form>





  </div>
</div>

{% endblock %}
```

[Link which contains image of form where i have problem](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nnZAO.jpg)

I am having trouble in getting the url of the image in the templates,guys please help me

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this in your `<form>`:

```
<div class="margintop50px">
    <img {% if object.image %} src="{{ object.image.url }}" {% else %} alt="You have no image." {% endif %}>
    <input type="file" name="image" accept="image/*">
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**
I just checked your views.py. Sorry for not noticing sooner, but your myproducts_update() function never .save()'s anything, so nothing will show because of that. Try changing that function to something like the following. It assumes the product has already been created somewhere else because I don't know of any other views you made to get this far *(maybe you originally added all pics/text from the admin panel? And personally, I would change the names of your function(s) because your form goes to `'create'`, but the function you showed states that this is about updating it, and that's generally not a clear path to follow when designing it because `create`ing something is different from `'update'`ing it. So if the following still doesn't work, I'll need to see your `'create'` view, and the urlpatterns for all these functions).*

Either way, there are better ways to improve the following *(such as what I talked about above),* but this is all I can give you without knowing that stuff:

**views.py**

```
def myproducts_update(request,product_id):
    product = get_object_or_404(Product,pk=product_id)
    if request.method == 'POST':
        product.body = request.POST.get('body', False)
        product.title = request.POST.get('title', False)
        product.url = request.POST.get('url', False)
        product.icon = request.FILES.get('icon', False)
        product.image = request.FILES.get('image', False)
        product.save()
    return render(request,'products/myproducts_update.html',{'product':product})
```

And then use the example template above to get it to show on that page.

Comment: Just edited it. I'm new to stack overflow, so I'm not sure if edits on my original post notify you on changes, but I know comments do so I'm saying it here too. Check everything below my UPDATE spot.